# how to invoke different UI controls?

Tags: vb.net, com, invoke, subform

```
    Private Sub FormStatusUpdate(Serverconnectionstatus as boolean) 
      If ServerConnectionStatus = True Then
         Try
            ' Enable Download/Upload/Sync Icon in Form
            For Each OpenedForms As Form In My.Application.OpenForms
                If Not TypeOf OpenedForms Is SplashScreen1 And Not TypeOf OpenedForms Is GroupOper Then
                    If OpenedForms.Text.EndsWith(")") Or OpenedForms.Text.EndsWith("*") Then
                        For Each ts_obj As ToolStrip In OpenedForms.Controls.OfType(Of ToolStrip)()
                            Dim btn_Updates1 = ts_obj.Items.Find("Download", True)
                            If btn_Updates1.Length > 0 Then
                                DirectCast(btn_Updates1(0), ToolStripItem).Enabled = True
                            End If
                            Dim btn_Updates2 = ts_obj.Items.Find("tsSync", True)
                            If btn_Updates2.Length > 0 Then
                                DirectCast(btn_Updates2(0), ToolStripItem).Enabled = True
                            End If
                            Dim btn_Updates3 = ts_obj.Items.Find("Upload", True)
                            If btn_Updates3.Length > 0 Then
                                DirectCast(btn_Updates3(0), ToolStripItem).Enabled = True
                            End If
                        Next
                    End If
                ElseIf TypeOf OpenedForms Is GroupOper Then
                    For Each gd_obj As Control In OpenedForms.Controls
                        If gd_obj.Name = "GoDownload" Or gd_obj.Name = "GoUpload" Then
                            gd_obj.Enabled = True
                        End If
                    Next
                End If
            Next....
```

Question: how to invoke the UI control located in the sub form?

My main form opened different sub forms during the initialization. The main form called a com object. The com object responded in a different thread. Now i need to notice some controls through the com object data_change events (Ini_DataGroup_DataChanged). I know how to inform the main form UI but not able to figure out those controls in the sub form. in other words, i am not sure how to call those subforms controls during the invoke.

here is the COM Object call the function.

```
Private Sub Ini_DataGroup_DataChanged(subscriptionHandle As Object, requestHandle As Object, values() As Opc.Da.ItemValueResult) Handles Ini_DataGroup.DataChanged
    MsgBox("ERROR")
    If values(0).Quality.Equals(Opc.Da.Quality.Good) And values(0).Value.ToString = "1" Then
        OPCConnectionBool = True
    Else
        Try
            OPCConnectionBool = False
            subscriptionHandle = Nothing
            OPCNetServer.Disconnect()
            OPCNetServer = Nothing
            OfflineNotification.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterScreen
            OfflineNotification.ShowDialog()
        Catch ex As Exception
            Exit Sub
        End Try
    End If

    Call FormStatusUpdate(OPCConnectionBool) ' Update Connection Status

End Sub
```

Obviously it throws a Exception says:  Cross Threads and Controls error, etc.
because the COM was created in different thread. those ts_obj toolstrip can not be manipulated by the com call.

How can i solve this issue? Thanks

Comment: I'm sure there are a number of ways this can be accomplished depending on how your code is structured. Please edit your question and provide more code showing how you are calling your sub forms so that we can provide an answer.

Comment: Are you getting any exceptions?...or just not finding the target control?

Answer (score 0):

I'd rewrite that like this:

```
    For Each OpenedForms As Form In My.Application.OpenForms
        If Not TypeOf OpenedForms Is SplashScreen1 And Not TypeOf OpenedForms Is GroupOper Then
            If OpenedForms.Text.EndsWith(")") Or OpenedForms.Text.EndsWith("*") Then
                For Each ts_obj As ToolStrip In OpenedForms.Controls.OfType(Of ToolStrip)()
                    Dim btn_Updates1 = ts_obj.Items.Find("Download", True)
                    If btn_Updates1.Length > 0 Then
                        DirectCast(btn_Updates1(0), ToolStripItem).Enabled = True
                    End If
                Next
            End If
        End If
    Next
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. this is much cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

You need to marshall your UI code onto the UI thread.

That means calling the `Invoke()` method on one of your forms.

To access the controls on the Subform from the main form, I would expose those controls via properties on the sub form:

```
Public ReadOnly Property SomeControl As TextBox
Get
  Return theTextBox
End Get
End Property
```

Comment: Not Really sure how to implement this. Basically Main Form called the COM, and COM responded with a data event change. the data event need to update some forms controls. Unfortunately these controls are not in the main form, and they are located in other forms.  I barely understand your code but not sure where I should add them. i really appreciate your help.

Comment: Can anyone help me here? i really appreciate.